# Are "from" and "gte"/"gt" equivalent in range query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, range-query

I've just discovered that a package that I use for ElasticSearch operations https://github.com/olivere/elastic creates the following range queries with `from`, `to`, `include_lower` and `include_upper` tags:

```
"query": {
    "range": {
        "myfield": {
            "from": 0.6666,
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true,
            "to": null
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) states that the following should be used.

```
"query": {
    "range": {
        "myfield": {
            "gte": 0.6666
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise the former (undocumented) works the same way as the latter. Are they equivalent? Should I expect that to work in the long run? Is that specified somewhere in ES?

Comment: https://github.com/olivere/elastic/issues/196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old format for range queries (using from/to/include_upper/include_lower) has been deprecated for serveral range queries in 0.90.4

And there are plans to remove support for the deprecated notation: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/48538#issuecomment-552642795

So if you don't like surprises, refactor the queries to the official range query notation.